How to format a number to currency in a textfield using a TextEditorController
I have a TextField that the user inputs a number which is a price. Right now, it displays as a number (i.e. 456000) without any formatting.
I want to be able to format it while the user is entering the number to be a currency (i.e. $456,000 or $456,000.00).
I have looked but I have not been able to find anything that works with TextField and TextEditorControllers.
Here is the code I am working on:
final moneyFormatter = NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");

TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: contractPriceController,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    contractPriceController.text = moneyFormatter.format(contractPriceController.text);
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Contract Price', labelText: 'Contract Price'),
                ),

This code did nothing but gave me the same unformatted number.
Can anyone share a good solution or example of how I would do this, please?
Thanks

Below solution works fine if you are dealing with only one type of currency.
 TextFormField(
                controller: contractPriceController,
                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,2}'))],
                autocorrect: false,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                decoration: InputDecoration(prefix: '$ ')
     )

You can add other required parameters in the TextFormField and above code should also work with TextField
Here inputFormatters provided allows numbers with a decimal and only two digits after decimal place.
Note: You would have to import services.dart to use FilteringTextInputFormatter
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
